# How to pass Oauth2.0 parameters to put request using python

Tags: python, oauth-2.0

is there a way to pass the following parameters to a post service?

I have tried multiple ways, but it doesn't work

```
import requests

auth = {
    'client_id' : 'telegram',
    'client_secret' : 'Welcome1',
    'username' : 'ut1',
    'password' : '123'
    'Access Token URL' : 'https://api.github.com/token'
}

r = requests.post('https://api.github.com', auth= auth,  verify=False)
```

Comment: What options have you tried? What results do you get? Any concrete error messages? Do you have a problem with making a post request or is there a problem with getting the token? By the way - are you sure you can get a token from Github just with these data? Have you tried any tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

i pass the Oauth2.0 parameters in headers params, this works for me.

```
def sendVerificationCodeSMS(tokenUrl, clientID, clientSecret, username, password, phoneNumber):
headers  =  {
                'Access Token URL': tokenUrl
                ,'Client ID': clientID
                ,'Client Secret': clientSecret
                ,'Username': username
                ,'Password': password
} 

response = requests.post('https://github.com/' + str(phoneNumber), headers = headers, verify=False) 

if (response.status_code == 201):
    try:
        response = response.json()
        verifCode = response["verificationCode"]
        return verifCode
        # print(verifCode)
    except:
        # print("Error al generar código de verificación")
        verifCode = 0
        return verifCode
else:
    print("No se ha podido enviar el código de verificación, intente nuevamente")
```